# What is a non blocking semaphore?

Tags: linux, multithreading, concurrency, mutex, semaphore

Seems like a contradiction because a semaphore should block to function.

<sub>Internet searches do not show up anything useful towards defining what this means.</sub>

Comment: Perhaps they're referring to something like a spinlock that depends on the using code to block or explicitly switch to another task? Where did you encounter the term?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a semaphore has the value 0, a down operation on it will block until someone releases a resource and increments the semaphore.

A non-blocking semaphore does not block on a down operation if the resource is unavailable, but rather yields an error. This can be useful if the program needs that resource immediately or without suspending execution, and if the resource isn't available, the program logic can rather do something else.

Answer (score 5):

A non-blocking semaphore typically refers to a semaphore which allows you to try to acquire *without blocking*.  If the semaphore can't be "locked", then it will fail but not block.  If it can be locked, it will lock it and return true (that it locked).

Answer (score 1):

The associated wait operation `WaitForSingleObject()` for example allows to specify a timeout value *dwMilliseconds*. If this parameter is set to `0` the result of the call will always return immedeately. This way the state of a semaphore can be tested without blocking.